# Вывод поля списка из json в react приложении

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Суть такова: необходимо вывести все температуры по дням, условно у меня 3 дня, температуры находятся в list->номер дня(от 0 до 2)->main->temp. Я понял как отдельно выводить температуру каждого дня, например data.list[1].main.temp, но я не понимаю как обратится к полям, чтобы достать все температуры.

```
class App extends React.Component {
        state = {days: []}
        const url = await fetch(`тут ссылка на api`);
        const data = await url.json();
        this.setState({days: data.list[1].main.temp});
    }
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `.map()`, например `days: data.list.map((item) => item.main.temp)` и получите массив темпретур

Comment: @SwaD спасибо большое, извиняюсь за еще один тупой вопрос как отделить пробелом эти элементы map

Comment: Эмм... даже не знаю как вам ответить. Представьте ЖД состав из множества вагонов. Вы можете между вагонами сделать разрыв? нет. Можно разрыв положить в вагон(к элементу массива добавить пробел), можно состав расцепить и поставить вагоны с разрывом, но это уже не массив. **Советую вам отложить React и уделить 30 минут теории** и прочитать про [массивы](https://learn.javascript.ru/array) и [строки](https://learn.javascript.ru/string),  узнать их методы и возможности их применения, думаю, вы сами сможете тогда ответить на ваш вопрос и это будет более полезно для Вас.